# How to implement duplex message pattern beween WF4 workflow service and WCF servcice

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4

I have a WF4 workflow service which has to communicate with the external WCF service which is a long running process. So could any one guide me how to implement durable duplex between worflow service and wcf with content correlation. I found samples in the internet to implement duplex communication between two workflow services but not between workflow service and WCF service.

Thanks In Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a few blog posts about using durable duplex commnuncications with WCF and WF4 last year that explain how to set this up. See [here](https://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2010/05/03/workflow-4-services-and-duplex-communications.aspx) and [here](https://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2010/05/04/more-workflow-4-services-and-duplex-communications.aspx). In these blog posts I used a workflow to call into a regular WCF service but there isn't a lot of difference if there are workflows on both sides, after all it is just WCF messaging between two different services

Comment: Thanks Maurice.  Could you share any article which has WCF and Workflow service duplex commnuication.